# Show that $\gcd\left(n^2+20,(n+1)^2+20\right)$ divides $81$ for all natural number $n.$

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Question:

> $$a_n=n^2+20$$ where $n$ is a natural number.
> $d_n$  denotes the greatest common divisor of $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$. Show that $d_n$ divides $81$ for all $n$.

I tried the question and got some results but could not prove what is asked to. I got $d_n$ divides $2n+1$ and $n(n-40)$ also I tried by checking congruences modulo $3$ and other numbers but ended up nowhere. I also came across a solution using Chinese remainder theorem while searching but did not understand it.

Comment: Thanks everyone for their solutions. Can any one help  using Chinese remainder theorem... I wanted to understand it.

Comment: **Hint** $\ {\rm mod}\ d\!:\ 0\equiv a_{n+1}\!-a_{n} = 1\!+\!2n\sim 1+2\sqrt{-20}\,\Rightarrow\,0\equiv (1+2\sqrt{-20})(1-2\sqrt{-20}) \equiv 81\,$ i.e . $n$ behaves like $\sqrt{-20}$ mod $d$ so we can take norms to get a rational multiple $= 81.\ $

Comment: @Dubuque Can u help.. how we write 1+2n~1+2(-20)^(1/2)?

Comment: $d\mid n^2+20\,\Rightarrow\, n^2\equiv -20\pmod d,\,$ so mod $d$ we see $n$ is a square root of $-20$ and we can exploit that property as as I did, i.e. the analogy shows $\,(1\!+\!2n)(1\!-\!2n) \equiv 1-4n^2\equiv 1-4(-20)\equiv 81$ since $\,n^2\equiv -20.\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque Thank you very much. Got it.

Answer (score 3):

If $d$ divides both $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$, it also divides $(2\,n+3)\,a_n-(2\,n-1)\,a_{n+1}=81$.

Answer (score 2):

As you noted, $d_n\mid 2n+1$.  So $d_n\mid (2n+1)^2=4n^2+4n+1$.

Also $d_n\mid n^2+20$.  So $d_n\mid 4(n^2+20)=4n^2+80$

Then $d_n\mid (4n^2+4n+1)-(4n^2+80)=4n-79$.

From this and $d_n\mid 2n+1$, you should be able to get your result.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Got it

Answer (score 2):

We have $$d_n=\gcd(a_n,a_{n+1})=\gcd(n^2+20,(n+1)^2+20)=\gcd(n^2+20,2n+1),$$ so $d_n\mid2n+1$ and $$d_n\mid4(n^2+20)=(2n)^2+80=(2n+1-1)^2+80=(2n+1)^2-2(2n+1)+81,$$ which leads to $d_n\mid81$.

Answer (score -1):

Hint : $d | n(n-40)$ $\Rightarrow$ $d | 2n^2 - 80n$